# htacess redirect to subfolder result in too many http status 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have one question and I dont find the solution.

I habe a subfolder in my web root an I want to redirect all URLs to this subfolder without changing the URL.

Ex: domain.com/article123.html ->redirecting-> domain.com/subfolder/article123.html but in addressbar stays domain.com/artcle123.com

so I put the following in my root htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subfolder/ /subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

But now when I test an URL with http://httpstatus.io I get the following

```
301 → Error while fetching URL. 11 redirect
```

in subfolder i have another htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "(.*)index.php"
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.(php|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/admin/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/images/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)?/templates/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [L]

##boosted CONTENT
RewriteRule (^[a-z]{2})/(.*/)?info/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html.* shop_content.php?language=$1&gm_boosted_content=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
RewriteRule (.*/)?info/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html.* shop_content.php?gm_boosted_content=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]

##boosted PRODUCTS
RewriteRule (^[a-z]{2})/(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html product_info.php?language=$1&gm_boosted_product=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
RewriteRule (.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.html product_info.php?gm_boosted_product=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]

##boosted CATEGORIES
RewriteRule (^[a-z]{2})/(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* index.php?language=$1&gm_boosted_category=$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule (.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?.* index.php?gm_boosted_category=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I dont know why. Can anyone help?

Comment: the URL is legal-dreams.biz and is redirecting to GX subfolder... in this subfolder I have another htaccess rewriting the URL for products, categories etc.

Comment: th root url is not causing any problems but every article-url for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root .htaccess looks fine, try this in `subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)\.(php|css|js|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(admin|images|templates)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

##boosted CONTENT
RewriteRule (^[a-z]{2})/(.*/)?info/([\w-]+)\.html shop_content.php?language=$1&gm_boosted_content=$3 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule (.*/)?info/([\w-]+)\.html shop_content.php?gm_boosted_content=$2 [QSA,L,NC]

##boosted PRODUCTS
RewriteRule (^[a-z]{2})/(.*/)?([\w-]+)\.html product_info.php?language=$1&gm_boosted_product=$3 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule (.*/)?([\w-]+)\.html product_info.php?gm_boosted_product=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

##boosted CATEGORIES
RewriteRule (^[a-z]{2})/(.*/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/? index.php?language=$1&gm_boosted_category=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule (.*/)?([\w-]+)/? index.php?gm_boosted_category=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! hmm unfortunately its the same result... I tried it with this URL: http://legal-dreams.biz/de/Raeuchermischung-Kush-2-5g.html with httpstatus.io, but result is the same :-(

Comment: Subdirectorys Name is "GX3"

Comment: Even when I opened this URL `http://legal-dreams.biz/Raeuchermischung-Kush-2-5g.html` it got 301 redirected to `http://legal-dreams.biz/de/Raeuchermischung-Kush-2-5g.html`. There is no rule in my answer that is adding `de/` in front. I suspect that is happening inside your code.

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! A script caused this problem. Was nothing with the /de but a there was a session-switch that redirects the site in a loop. I deleted this script and now everything look fine. Thank you, you made my day!!